# Problem using tensorflow's multilingual universal-sentence-encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I'm trying to download Google's new pretrained multilingual universal sentence encoder that was just published July this year. I have followed the test found at their website using Colab and works well, but when I try to do it locally it hangs forever while trying to download it (code copied from [tf's site](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1)):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import tf_sentencepiece

# Some texts of different lengths.
english_sentences = ["dog", "Puppies are nice.", "I enjoy taking long walks along the beach with my dog."]
italian_sentences = ["cane", "I cuccioli sono carini.", "Mi piace fare lunghe passeggiate lungo la spiaggia con il mio cane."]
japanese_sentences = ["犬", "子犬はいいです", "私は犬と一緒にビーチを散歩するのが好きです"]

#hangs here:
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1")
```

I have installed all dependencies and packages. Other simpler models work (English sentence encoder for example), only happens with this new one. Any ideas? Thank you all!

Comment: Hello everyone, still no success. Strangely atom was not prompting the error so I ran the code in VS code and get a 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'. It is so weird that the code runs as it is no changes in colab, but fails to run locally. Thought it was a package version compatibility issue but all packages are the same as in colab. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Found and resolved the problem for anyone interested. It appears to be a compatibility problem between tensorflow 1.14 and tf-sentencepiece 0.1.82.1. To resolve it, simply downgrade tensorflow 1.14 to 1.13.1, as stated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/345), worked for me.